# Reformat text by adding html tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on an e-commerce site, and I have a problem formatting the prices in the way it is designed.

It displays the price this way :

```
 <p class="price">£900.00</p>
```

I need to get all the prices displayed in the site (class price) and reformat it this way:

```
<p class="price"><span>£</span> 900 <span>.00<span></p>
```

so after I can add specific css styles to the decimals and the £ sign

Do you have any idea to do this?

BTW I need to do it via JS / jquery because I did it in the Back -end And it generated some conflicts, so it needs to be done on the client

Thanks in advance

Comment: A little observation... the `:` should be `=`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to do this in the frontend, as it would be better to point us with the backend "conflict", nevertheless:

```
$(function(){

  var $el, price;

  $('.price').each(function(item){

    $el = $(this);
    price = $el.text().substr(1);
    $el.empty().append(

      $("<span></span>", { class : "currency", text: "£"})

    ).append( price.split('.')[0])
    .append(

      $("<span></span>", { class : "decimals", text: "." + price.split('.')[1]})    

    );

  });

});
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WdTFr/).

Answer (score 4):

The following will work for all kinds of currency symbols. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/EWgwr/) is the working fiddle.

```
$('.price').each(function (idx, val) {
    var price = $(this).text();
    var newOne = price.match(/^(.)(\d+)\.(\d+)$/);
    $(this).html("<span>" + newOne[1] + "</span>" + newOne[2] + ".<span>" + newOne[3] + "</span>");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WdTFr/4/)

This will work for string like :   `£900.00` , `£900000.00123`  , `$560125.14500` and you know the rest..

```
var val = '£900.00';
var currSign = val.charAt(0);
```

`currSign` will be `£`

```
var amount = val.substring(1);
```

`amount` will be `900.00`

```
 var left = amount.split('.')[0];
 var right = "."+amount.split('.')[1];
```

`left` will be `900`
`right` will be `.00`

Use it anyway You like.

```
<p class="price"><span>$currSign</span> $left <span>$right<span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("p.price").each(function() {
    var oldprice = $(this).text();
    var split = oldprice.match(/^£(\d+)(\.\d+)$/);
    if (split) {
       $(this).html('<span>£</span> ' + split[1] + ' <span>'+split[2]+'</span>');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.price').each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).text().replace(/(£)(\d+)(\.\d\d)/, '<span>$1</span> $2 <span>$3</span>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
$('.price').html(function(i,h){
    return h.replace(/([£$])(\d+)(.\d{2})/,'<span>$1</span><span>$2</span><span>$3</span>');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/nvr6p/).

- The `([£$])` captures a currency character that's either `£` or `$`,
- `(\d+)` captures one, or more, numeric characters,
- `(.\d{2})` captures a period and two following numbers.

The `$1`, `$2` and `$3` refer to each of these matches in turn.

And to style these (even without explicit class-names:

```
p span {
    color: #000;
}

p span:first-child {
    color: #999;
}

span:first-child + span {
    font-weight: bold;
}

span:last-child {
    font-size: 80%;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/nvr6p/1/).

References:

- [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/).
- [JavaScript Regular Expressions (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).